# random between variables

Tags: sql, random

Lets say I have 3 variables in sql:

`var1`, `var2` and `var3`

Can I choose on of these by random?
I do not want to have a range set by variable, I just need the random function to pick one of my variables.

For example:

```
DECLARE @First INT
DECLARE @Second INT
DECLARE @Third INT

SET @First = 1
SET @Second = 2
SET @Third = 3
```

And I would get a random value: 1,2 or 3

Thanks

Comment: `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Comment: @TobiasR. That's very product specific. Which dbms?

Comment: Add more info. Tag the dbms used - you need a product specific answer!

Comment: Sorry, I use Microsoft SQL server management studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @TobiasR's Idea of ordering and Limiting i made this:

```
declare @var1 nvarchar(max)
declare @var2 nvarchar(max)
declare @var3 nvarchar(max)

set @var1 = 'X'
set @var2 = 'Y'
set @var3 = 'Z'

x.* into #temp 
from (
select @var1 as var , rand() as rand
union 
select @var2, rand() 
union 
select @var3, rand()
) x

select top 1 * from #temp 
order by rand

drop table #temp
```

The basic Idea is assigning every variable a random number and then selecting the one with the lowest assigned value.

Or without the use of a temporary Table by using NEWID() as sorting value: (credits to @ughai)

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (VALUES(@var1),(@var2),(@var3)) as T(a) ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: or even shorter as 

`SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (VALUES(@var1),(@var2),(@var3)) as T(a) ORDER BY NEWID()`

Comment: @ughai nice use of NEWID(), i will add that to my answer